# How to make zend to set time_zone in sql

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I tried to execute a sql query that contains `set time_zone='+8:00';` in zend, but couldn't execute it because of this string.

How do I make so that it run the query properly?

Code:

```
    $sql = "set time_zone='+8:00';
            SELECT
            n.id,
            ...";
    $query=$this->_db->query($sql);
    $fetch=$query->fetchAll();

    return $fetch;
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: It doesn't produce any error message. Just blank. I've tried try and catch statement, also didn't work. However, the query works if I use directly in workbench or phpmyadmin.

Comment: Blank page often means there was PHP error. What is in your web server error log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should separate the two queries. The Zend_Db objects aren't retrieving any results if you first use mysql `SET` command, or execute two queries at once

First use:

```
$this->_db->query('set time_zone='+8:00';');
```

Then, on a second line:

```
$Query = $this->_db->query('SELECT n.id FROM ...')
```

And then you can fetch results or loop through them

```
while($Result = $Query->fetch()) {
    print_r($Result);
}
```

Or use

```
$Query->fetchAll()
```

Comment: Will this affect other queries as well? Or just when this query is executed? Anyhow, thanks. This works.

Comment: This will affect all queries that you execute in this connection. You need to set the timezone again after creating a new connection with the MySQL service.

Comment: You mean it affect based on per fetchAll() query or other connection outside this query as well? For example, I have another action in this controller that connects to the db. Does it affect this action too?